# Finding close words to searched word in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am trying to write a query in MongoDB that find words that are in a specific distance from the searched word. An example would be trying to find all words that are exactly next to the searched word **table**. The results could be:

- the (table)
- black (table)
- old (table)
- (table) with
- (table) and

Right now my collection called **words** looks like this:

```
{
  'article_id': 1,
  'word_id': 19,
  'word': 'black'
},
{
  'article_id': 1,
  'word_id': 20,
  'word': 'table'
}
```

Where **article_id** is the article number and **word_id** is the position of the word in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
db.Words.find({"word":"sth"}).forEach(function(word) {
    word = db.Products.findOne({"word_id":(word.word_id-1)})
    printjson(word)
})
```

So for each result you query new one. This is the only way. Or you can use Hadoop, Java, C#, python,..